# How to disable TNT block damage in MCPE?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm trying to make a PVP arena and I want to include TNT. How do I make it so that it won't damage the blocks, but still damage the players?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to summon a TNT that doesn't destroy its surroundings?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/383267/how-to-summon-a-tnt-that-doesnt-destroy-its-surroundings)

Comment: (The above is a newer question, but it's higher-quality and has an actual answer)

Answer (score 0):

I can't be done. To combat this issue, I suggest using indestructible blocks like obsidian and bedrock.
Or, use creepers and turn off mob griefing.

Hope this helps!