# How to summon a TNT that doesn't destroy its surroundings?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

In the server The Hive, they have a special item called Boom Boxes, and what it essentially does is that they act like normal TNT, but with some custom bits, and can also be thrown. Now I want to try and replicate the Normal type, where it just gives damage to the entity, but not on the blocks.

So I found [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/266750/how-can-i-summon-tnt-without-causing-damage-to-blocks), but I have no idea how to do it properly, plus, it is a Java question.

So what I want to try and do is to not summon a mob in the process, activate the TNT regularly, then explode with no debris or damage left behind.

The only thing I thought of is using a repeating command block:

```
execute @e[type=tnt] ~ ~ ~ setblock ~ ~ ~ water
```

Then another command where it removes the water, but I don't know how to detect the TNT no longer existing.

I thought of some solution, but it will only work in a certain plot of land and on a flat world, and has other inconsistencies.

```
fill 50 1 50 -50 3 -50 grass
kill @e[type=item, name=Dirt]
```

So how can I go about doing this?

Comment: [Pretty much a dupe of this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/191684/1351) except the linked question is Java Edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a repeating command block and a chain command block like this:
First command:

```
execute @e[type=tnt] ~ ~ ~ summon Creeper ~ ~ ~ minecraft:start_exploding
```

The second command (in the chain block):

```
kill @e[type=tnt]
```

You need to make sure to disable mob griefing by:

```
/gamerule mobgriefing false
```

You can set the repeating command block to `Needs Redstone` and activate it by placing a Redstone block when you need to use the feature.

Answer (score 1):

When the TNT is about to explode, you need to spawn a creeper with a low fuse at its location, kill the TNT and quickly disable mob griefing. This can be accomplished by setting a scoreboard timer and checking if any creeper entities with a specific tag exist, and if not, enable mobGriefing again. (I have verified this works on Bedrock Edition, with the exact commands amount I said unless you want to implement the scoreboard timer and tags for turning on mobGriefing again.)

Answer (score 0):

You could summon TNT with an invisible water block underneath it, making it explode but not destroy anything.

Answer (score -3):

I'm not sure you can do this without advanced coding, although I would recommend the "To Much TNT" Mod. It adds lots of new, different TNT's, including throwable dynamite. Apart from that, there are lots of cheaper and free mods/Add ons that are good, to. Sorry I couldn't be more of a help :(

Comment: this is bedrock. mods dont exist